# Listbox SelectedIndexCollection versus SelectedIndices

Tags: vb.net, listbox, generic-programming, undo-redo

I am working on a Generic Undoclass for a number of custom controls and got stuck when trying to implement undo for multiselect listboxes.

the Undo Class:

```
Public Class UndoClass(Of T)
    Private FirstValue As T
    Private PrevValue As T
    Private CurrentValue As T
    Private HasValue As Boolean
    Public Sub Add(ByVal Item As T)
        If Not HasValue Then
            FirstValue = Item
            PrevValue = Item
            HasValue = True
        ElseIf Not CurrentValue.Equals(Item) Then
            If Not CurrentValue.Equals(FirstValue) Then PrevValue = CurrentValue
        End If
        CurrentValue = Item
    End Sub
```

and some undo code. In the custom Listbox class I added:

```
dim undoing as new UndoClass(Of SelectedIndexCollection)

Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(e As EventArgs)
    undoing.add(me.SelectedIndices)
    ....
Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As EventArgs)
    if me.SelectedIndex>=0 then undoing.add(me.selectedIndices)
    ....
```

The problem I encountered was that the passed "Item" did not expose the same properties as the originating SelectedIndices properties and therefore the CurrentValue.equals(item) test always fails. Although vs helpfile clearly states that the selectedIndices is a "ListBox.SelectedIndexCollection containing the indexes of the currently selected items in the control" the way I did it does not work (it works with all my other controls where I just pass their .text values as strings or .Checked values as Boolean etc...).

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that `SelectedIndices` is a read-only property.

Comment: What I have done in the past is base the Undo on the control type not what is being undone - in some cases there are more than one thing to watch.  List controls are a pain - since you cant outright set collection properties, you can loop the `SelectedObjectCollection` and store the hashcode of each item in a List.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to solve it (just a test routine so I used function returning test info instead of methods and short variable names):

```
Public Class TestListClass(Of T)
    Dim Current As New List(Of T)
    Dim Prev As New List(Of T)
    Public Function add(T1 As List(Of T)) As String
        Dim s As String = String.Empty
        If T1.GetType.IsGenericType Then    ' better safe then sorry and we'll need that in the final version
            Dim ar As Type() = T1.GetType.GenericTypeArguments
            s = ar(0).ToString
        End If
        If Current.Count = 0 Then
            For Each X As T In T1
                Current.Add(X)
            Next
            Return "created " & s & vbNewLine
        Else
            If Prev.Count > 0 Then Prev.Clear()
                For Each X As T In Current
                    Prev.Add(X)
                Next
                Current.Clear()
                For Each X As T In T1
                    Current.Add(X)
                Next
                Return "pushed " & s & vbNewLine
            End If
        End Function
        Public Function Listing() As String
            Dim S As String = String.Empty
            If Prev.Count > 0 Then
                S &= "Prev= " & Enumerate(Prev) & vbNewLine
            End If
            If Current.Count > 0 Then
                S &= "Current= " & Enumerate(Current) & vbNewLine
            End If
            Return S
        End Function
        Private Function Enumerate(T1 As List(Of T)) As String
            Dim s As String = String.Empty
            For I = 0 To T1.Count - 1
                s &= T1.Item(I).ToString & csComa
            Next
            Return s
        End Function
Public Function Compare(T1 As List(Of T)) As String
    Dim s As String = Enumerate(T1)
    If ListsSame(Current, T1) Then
        s &= "is same as current! (" & Enumerate(Current) & ")"
    ElseIf ListsSame(Prev, T1) Then
        s &= "is same as Previous! (" & Enumerate(Prev) & ")"
    Else
        s &= "does not match!"
    End If
    Return s & vbNewLine
End Function
    Private Function ListsSame(T1 As List(Of T), T2 As List(Of T)) As Boolean
        Dim ok As Boolean = False
        If T1.Count > T2.Count Then
            ok = T1.Except(T2).Any
        Else
            ok = T2.Except(T1).Any
        End If
        Return Not ok
    End Function
End Class
```

I had to iterate through the list in the 'add' routine as the equality operator would create a reference to the current value instead of copying the content

The test code:

```
Dim t1 As New TestListClass(Of Integer), l1 As New List(Of Integer), t2 As New TestListClass(Of String), l2 As New List(Of String)
Dim x1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
l1.AddRange(x1)
Me.txtResult.Text = t1.add(l1)
Dim y1() As Integer = {6, 7, 8}
Dim l11 As New List(Of Integer)
l11.AddRange(y1)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t1.add(l11)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t1.Listing
Me.txtResult.Text &= t1.Compare(l1)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t1.Compare(l11)
l11.Add(9)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t1.Compare(l11)
Dim x2() As String = {"10", "20", "30"}
l2.AddRange(x2)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t2.add(l2)
Dim y2() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}
Dim l22 As New List(Of String)
l22.AddRange(y2)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t2.add(l22)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t2.Listing
Me.txtResult.Text &= t2.Compare(l2)
Me.txtResult.Text &= t2.Compare(l22)
l22.Add("d")
Me.txtResult.Text &= t2.Compare(l22)
```

The output:

```
created System.Int32
pushed System.Int32
Prev= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
Current= 6, 7, 8, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, is same as Previous! (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, )
6, 7, 8, is same as current! (6, 7, 8, )
6, 7, 8, 9, does not match!
created System.String
pushed System.String
Prev= 10, 20, 30, 
Current= a, b, c, 
10, 20, 30, is same as Previous! (10, 20, 30, )
a, b, c, is same as current! (a, b, c, )
a, b, c, d, does not match!
```

Next I intend to split the operations based on gettype.IsgenericType when selectedItem or SelectedValue is passed as base variables.